# Direct Routing Reporting - Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Using the Microsoft Graph API to create reports doesn't seem to cover many of the user scenarios we want to see, e.g. queue statistics, missed calls, calls answered/missed etc.

Has someone here experience with it and how to address those limitations if possible?

Regards
Andri

Comment: Hi @Andri Örvar Baldvinsson, we are taking this to our internal team, will update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Andri Örvar Baldvinsson,This item remains on the backlog in Teams UserVoice,
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com).